# Is there a shortcut key in Delphi to go to the last modified location?

Tags: eclipse, delphi, ide, shortcut

In Eclipse there is a shortcut key `CRTL+Q` will take me to the last modified location.

Does Delphi also has such a shortcut key? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/Default_IDE_Shortcut_Keys 

"Ctrl + Q + P  Moves cursor to previous position"   - maybe not quite what you mean, though.

Comment: Yeah I have got there, but disappointed. @Mawg

Comment: No, there is not. You might use `Ctrl-Z` (undo, also affects caret movements) to eventually move back to the last edited location.

Comment: Smart (+1) - especially if immediately followed by Ctrl + Shift + Z (redo)

Comment: Yeah undo is the answer

Comment: There are many difference while compare with the `Ctrl+Z` in Delphi and the shortcut `Ctrl+Q` in Eclipse (or IntelliJ  IDEA/PyCharm/PhpStorm). The first is that the latter can jump from a different file back to where it was just edited, the second is that Delphi's `Ctrl+Z` will change the cursor place even when there is not edited but just moved the cursor. @Tom @David

Comment: I'm not sure whether you misread my previous comment or I yours. I answered your question, *Is there a shortcut key in Delphi to go to the last modified location?* with: *No, there is not*, didn't I? Then I offered `Ctrl-Z` as a substitute that *might be* useful. If you don't think it is useful, simply don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Code_Editor

Finding the Next and Previous Changes

As you edit code, you can use keystrokes to quickly navigate to the Next and the Previous changes that you have made. The keyboard shortcuts are:

```
Ctrl+Shift+F7 -- moves to the previous line modified since the file was opened (green marking in the gutter).

Ctrl+Shift+F8 -- moves to the next line modified since the file was opened (green marking in the gutter).

Alt+Shift+F7 -- moves to the previous line modified since the last save (yellow marking in the gutter).

Alt+Shift+F8 -- moves to the next line modified since the last save (yellow marking in the gutter).
```